# RLE Compression

Tags: java, loops

I have the following java code for an RLE Compression algorithm:

```
public static String compress (String original) {
    String compressed = "";
    char letter = 0;
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++)  {
        if (letter == original.charAt(i)) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        else {
            compressed = compressed + letter;
            if(count != 1) {
                compressed = compressed + count;
            }
            letter = original.charAt(i);
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    compressed = compressed + letter;
    if(count != 1) {
        compressed = compressed + count;
    }
    return compressed;
}
```

If the input is `aaaawwwweerrr`

The output should be: `3a4w2e3r`

The actual output is: `a3w4e2r3`

I tried switching

```
compressed = compressed + count
```

to

```
compressed = count + compressed
```

but when I do that the output is: 244 awer3

How should I modify the code so that the output is in the appropriate sequence?

Comment: Which of the two occurrences did you change?

Comment: The if statement within the else statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(count != 1){
  compressed = compressed + count;
}
compressed = compressed + letter;
```

First append the `count` and then `letter`.

This you need to do at two places, first `inside the loop` and second `after the loop` completes for the last character.

I would suggest you make use of `StringBuilder.append()` instead of `String` concatenation.

```
public static String compress (String original) {
  StringBuilder compressed = new StringBuilder();
  char letter = 0;
  int count = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++) {
    if (letter == original.charAt(i)) {
      count = count + 1;
    }
    else {
      compressed = count !=1 ? compressed.append(count) : compressed;
      compressed.append(letter);
      letter = original.charAt(i);
      count = 1;
    }
  }

  compressed = count !=1 ? compressed.append(count) : compressed;
  compressed.append(letter);
  return compressed.toString();
}
```

```
Input : aaaawwwweerrr
Output: 4a4w2e3r
```

Answer (score -2):

See this code:

```
public class RunLengthEncoding {

  String s1 = "aaawwweerrr" ;

  public void compressed ( String s1) {
    int count =0;
    char temp = s1.charAt(0);
    for(int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++) {
      if (s1.charAt(i) == temp) {
        count++;
      }
      else {
        System.out.print(temp + ""+ count+" ");
        count =1;
        temp = s1.charAt(i);
      }
    }
  }
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
    RunLengthEncoding obj = new RunLengthEncoding();
    obj.compressed(obj.s1);
  }
}
```